# not able to customizeTitleBar in windows flutter

Tags: windows, flutter

i want to customize windows title bar but when i am trying it, or run my code it show nothing, please guide me to customize Title bar. I want to make it transparent.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
    import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:transaction_managment/Screens/HomeScreen.dart';
    import 'package:win32/win32.dart';

    void main() {
      if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
        // Initialize FFI
        sqfliteFfiInit();
      }
      // Change the default factory. On iOS/Android, if not using `sqlite_flutter_lib` you can forget
      // this step, it will use the sqlite version available on the system.
      databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});
    
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'AccountAce',
          theme: ThemeData(
            // This is the theme of your application.
            //
            // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
    // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
    // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
    // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
    // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
    // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
    // is not restarted.
            primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }

    void customizeTitleBar() {
```

// Get the handle to the current window
final hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

// Set the title bar background color to red

// Add a custom button to the title bar
final hMenu = CreateMenu();
AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, 0x1000, TEXT("Custom Button"));

```
      final hMenuBar = CreateMenu();
      AppendMenu(hMenuBar, MF_POPUP, hMenu, TEXT("Custom Menu"));

      GetMenu(
        hWnd,
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flutter package for it, go and search pub.dev. now search for windows title bar , then a list of plugins will appears